# Android: how to handle day/night themes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I'm building an Android app and I need to have two different themes for day and night modes: different colors and different drawables.

What is the best way to do it?

I've noticed a service called UiModeManager but I'm not sure if it behaves like I expect. I've placed two different bitmaps (with the same name) in drawable-mdpi and drawable-night-mdpi and I created an Activity that shows that bitmap.

I've tried to switch the day/night mode by putting in the onCreate():

```
    UiModeManager uiManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);
    uiManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

But Android always shows the "day" version.

Any suggestion or hint would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Maurizio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HoneycombGallery Sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/index.html) has a day/night switcher for the theme (background + drawables etc.). They only defined two themes and set it in code via `setTheme()`. Maybe that helps you

Edit: According to docs [setNightMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html#setNightMode%28int%29) "Changes to the night mode are only effective when the car or desk mode is enabled on a device."